# jQuery drop function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my code in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MAAAAAN/cmpmd1os/7/)

Why doesn't the drop function fire? Over does not fire either.

I am using the following headers

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: your fiddle doesn't have those headers, it needs jquery to work

Comment: oh sorry i will see how i add them

Comment: i dont know how to add those headers in the fiddle, hopefully you can help me without them.

Answer (score -1):

The droppable method was outside of the initialize function i moved it inside and now it works